# Installing Python for AD users

Tags: python-3.x, active-directory

I have a Windows AD and would like to let my users run Python. with administrative credentials, the user installs Python, installs the libraries needed, but when the attempts to run the code, the libraries aren't being found. You run a cmd with elevated permissions, pip install the package and you get that the package has been already installed.

What would be the correct way to install Python for Windows domain users where they can run code, preferably by not forcing them to be administrators :) ?

Comment: I would use Python package from MS Store, you'll get an autoupgrade for free.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is users can't install libraries by themselves, and using elevated credentials, the packages are installed for the elevated user and no the standar user.

Comment: For me it does not. MS Store application is local to user and everything is installed per user. For example, my installed urllib3 is located in `c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages`

Comment: You are right Raspy. That's how it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Python from the MS Store can be done by restricted users. Installing packages, as @Raspy said, can be done without running an elevated command prompt